# Сохранение значений Radiobutton для настройки положения формы с помощью кнопки в C# Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

У меня есть главная форма, на которой есть кнопка для перехода к форме с настройками. На этой форме с настройками есть кнопка изменения цвета формы, кнопка изменения шрифта и кнопка применения изменений, а также GroupBox с 4-мя radiobutton'ами, при помощи которых можно изменить положение этой и главной формы. Как можно при помощи кнопки применения изменений сохранить значения Radiobutton'ов, чтобы при повторном открытии формы настроек был выбран ранее нажатый radiobutton?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ зависит от того как вы открываете форму во второй раз.

1. Если заново создаете - то перед тем как закрыть в первый раз форму сохраняйте состояние и заполняйте поля, значения во время создания второй формы и показываете.
2. Если вы скрываете форму то во время нажатия кнопки устанавливаете `radioButton1.Checked = true;`

Comment: А у Вас, случаем,  нет примера, как сохранять состояние? Буду очень признателен, если покажете

Comment: примера нет. это обычный класс который хранит данные. class MyFormData и поля.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы работаете в Visual Studio, то:

1.В свойствах проекта необходимо **сохранить параметр** пользовательских **настроек**.

Проект - Свойства проекта - **Имя: chk, Тип: bool, Область: Пользователь**

2.**В коде формы** написать:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.chk = radioButton1.Checked;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radioButton1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.chk;
}
```

3.**В событиях формы** в режиме конструктора **указать ссылки**:

Для кнопки - Действие - **Click: button1_Click**

Для формы - Поведение - **Load: Form3_Load**

Обратите внимание, что radioButton после его включения изменить значение нельзя, а checkBox можно. Поэтому необходимо для radioButton написать условие (при котором radioButton1 становится false, когда значение radioButton2 - true), либо
использовать checkBox. Замените radioButton1 на checkBox1 и будет вам счастье.

Выбранные пользователем параметры хранятся в файле **App.config**.